# Where to get Outside Data from RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview, remoteview

I need to populate a `ListView` in a Homescreen `Widget`.  I know I use `RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory` as a sort of `Adapter`.

I also know how to populate the rows in `getViewAt()` method to show this.

However, I need to populate an `ArrayList` of Objects from the Network and pass that into the `getViewAt()`  *I am not sure where or how to go about doing this?*

In a normal adapter, I simply pass this in the constructor.  Would it be the same here?

Comment: I'd recommend you to search for tutorials on the web, luckily there are lots of them.

Comment: @Egor I have not found the same thing. I will continue looking.

Comment: Have checked this demo of ListView Widget? https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget